# Application of Hahn Banach for normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $X$ be a normed space. I want to show that - using Hahn Banach - for every $x$ we have

$$||x|| = \sup\{|f(x)| : f \in X^*, ||f|| \leq 1\}$$

One direction is easy:

$$|f(x)| \leq ||f|| \cdot ||x|| \leq ||x||$$

Therefore

$$||x|| \geq \sup\{|f(x)| : f \in X^*, ||f|| \leq 1\}$$

For the other direction one uses Hahn-Banach.

Defining $g: \mathbb{R}x \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(tx) = t||x||$$

We can conclude by Hahn-Banach that there exists $g': X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $||g'|| = ||g||$. We know that $||g|| = 1$ therefore $||g'|| = 1$.

If I now choose $f = g'$, how can I derive that $|f(x)| = ||x||$, to show that $||x|| \leq \sup\{|f(x)| : f \in X^*, ||f|| \leq 1\}$

Comment: $g'$ can be chosen to extend $g$, and so $|g'(x)| = |g(x)| = \Vert x \Vert$.

Comment: With your definition of $g(tx) = t\|x\|$ you have $g(x) = \|x\|$. Since, as you said, $\|g\| = \|g'\|$ and $|g(x)| = \|x\|$ it follows.